# Can faulty motherboard cause these absurdly high Read/Seek error rates?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

I have two similar Seagate HDDs used in a laptop. The laptop suffered from various problems caused by faulty motherboard. Now, I need to use one of these for temporary storage and both of these drives have surprisingly high Raw Read and Seek error rates (and also the Command Timeout value is very high). I noticed that these drives are very sensitive to movement (usually when lifting the laptop from the table) and therefore the G-Sense error rate might not mean that the drives fell or they were very badly handled. Spin-Up time is surprisingly zero.

Do you think it is safe to use these drives? Failure of the hard drive would be very unpleasant but acceptable.

One of the drives sometimes produced very bad sounds. (And that was fixed by knocking the laptop a bit. I take frequent backups, so HDD failure is not very bad for me.) The SMART report below is probably from this drive, but I am not sure, because both of the drives were always used together.

These drives do not report anything like bad blocks.

So, the question is: Can faulty motherboard cause such high error rates? (Ignoring the bad sounds, one of the drives is definitely in a bad state.)

---

SMART report for both of the drives looks nearly the same. This is the one with worse G-Sense error rate (some entries are omitted for brevity).

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   117   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       121727432
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       273624553
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       8590065670
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       370
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Comment: I remember, almost 20 years ago a defect bios + some WD harddrives caused the destruction of the drives.... in a perfect world the firmware of the drive would protect the drive, but maybe wrong commands or missing power from the motherboard could cause a drive to get damaged - of course!

Comment: I think that the motherboard could do any “funny” thing to the drive that is possible (bad power, bad commands, bad connection, …).

Comment: The big numbers may just be a Seagate thing, a way they reports raw values. The big numbers may actually be several values combined.

Comment: If these are internal drives how did you determine if sound was from hard drive or something else inside laptop. Fans would be my first suspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMART attributes are reported by the disk's firmware and
are completely unrelated to the motherboard. These are errors
that arrive inside the disk while the firmware is executing I/O
commands. The motherboard is not a factor here.

Your disks seem indeed to be in a "Pre-fail" state, use at your own risk.

Comment: Yes, I know. But can the faulty MB cause so high error rates? The other drive did never make such bad sounds, but the error rates are nearly the same.

Comment: I modified my answer - hope this is clearer.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. It's time to get new HDDs.

Comment: How was it determined the drive is in pre-fail state? Scary big RAW values do not mean by definition a drive is in pre-fail state. The big scary number may be actually several values combined.

Comment: @jiwopene I disagree. I had once a brand new Seagate drive which was showing very large raw values for Read_Error_Rate and Seek_Error_Rate, and I was worried too. But after some research it appeared that these values did not suggest a failing drive at all. See http://www.users.on.net/%7Efzabkar/HDD/Seagate_SER_RRER_HEC.html . Raw values are meaningless if you don't know exactly what they represent and their units (and some amount of read errors is perfectly normal on any drive). You should look only at the normalized values, and on your drive they are well above the pre-fail thresholds.

Comment: @PierU Exactly my point.

Comment: Nowhere in my answer did I refer to raw values. The *normalized* values are bad and the disk makes knocking sounds, meaning that it's dying. Don't criticize and downvote correct answers.

Comment: @harrymc the normalized values are nowhere near bad here. The worst one is 84 for the Seek_Error_Rate, which is still well above the threshold (30 for this attribute). A "pre-fail" state means that some normalized values are below their threshold, which is not the case here: so, no it isn't in a pre-fail state. This drive probably requires some monitoring to check if the suspicious attributes are stable or tend to evolve negatively. If they are stable then there's no need to worry (and BTW I didn't downvote your answer, even though yes I am criticizing the last part of it).

Comment: @PierU: The eternal question : How many bad sectors justify replacing the disk. But when bad sectors are coupled with strange sounds, there's no question about what needs to be done.

Comment: @harrymc NO bad sector is reported by SMART in the above case. The drive may have some problem, it's not impossible, but this is definitely not from the SMART report that we could conclude that.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.disktuna.com/big-scary-raw-s-m-a-r-t-values-arent-always-bad-news/

Same goes for for example see:

> **3.5 Attribute ID 7: Seek Error Rate**
>
> Monitor seeks requiring one or more retries. Exclude calibration seeks
> and seeks in system area.
>
> Normalized Seek Error Rate = 10 * log10(SeekCount / SeekErrors) which
> is only updated when SeekCount is in the range 106 to 109. The counts
> are cleared when SeekCount = 109 . (Evaluates to a value from 1 to
> 100).
>
> **Raw Usage**
>
> Raw [3 – 0] = Number of seeks
>
> Raw [5 – 4] = Number of seek errors

In your example, 273624553 > x00 x00 x10 x4F x2D xE9 > 273624553 is number of seeks, no errors.